# how to deal with an undefined query variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following to launch dialogs in my app:

```
$('.dialogDo').live('click', function() {

    // Do we have a custom width?
    var width = this.search.match(/width=(\d+)/)[1];
    if (width) {
        dialogDo(this.href, width);
    }
    else {
        dialogDo(this.href, 480);
    }

    return false;
});
```

This works fine if width is defined in the href which trigger the click function above. Problem is if width is not defined it breaks. How can I deal with an undefined width while still maintaining the functionality to use a width if provided?

Thanks

Comment: could you host it on jsfiddle

Comment: Why do you use this.search.match(/width=(\d+)/)[1] instead of $(this).width() ?

Comment: if you run this code var a;
if(a)
    alert("an");
else
    alert("b"); you will find that b will be alerted.. thus your check for width is fine.. must be sm other prob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to have a default width in place.

```
var matched = this.search.match(/width=(\d+)/);
var width = matched ? matched[1] : DEFAULT_WIDTH;
```

Edit -- match can return null if there are no matches and you can't index into null. (thanks @Chris)

Comment: Just noticed what you are doing. Yea, follow @Simon Arnold's suggestions... don't actually check for a set width attribute like this!

Comment: I really like this but it is giving an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I believe changing || to : works right as a ternary operator?

Comment: @ColdTree, I botched my last edit. Thanks for pointing that out, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript match function returns null if it doesn't match and an array of results if so. So you need to check that the result is actually an array before indexing it with `[1]`. For example:

```
var width = this.search.match(/width=(\d+)/);
if (width) {
    dialogDo(this.href, width[1]);
}
else {
    dialogDo(this.href, 480);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.dialogDo').live('click', function() {

    // Do we have a custom width?
    var width = this.search.match(/width=(\d+)/)[1];
    if (!isNaN(width)) {
        dialogDo(this.href, width);
    }
    else {
        dialogDo(this.href, 480);
    }

    return false;
});
```